# How to format Ubuntu bootable USB?

Tags: usb, 12.10, format

I am new in Ubuntu. First I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my USB stick which is of 16 GB. So, it installed with 2 partitions of 9 GB and 7 GB.

Now I want to format that USB. But when I try to format it, only ext4 one does get formatted but not the partition which is the swap memory. Now on other OS my USB shows only 8.5 GB.

Comment: Are you booting to a different device than the one you're trying to format / partition?

Answer (score 14):

Neither of the two existing answers solved my problem.

I needed to go to the Disks app and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> to get a prompt to actually format the USB drive.

Thanks to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769079/cant-format-ubuntu-installation-stick).

Comment: In Ubuntu 19, now it has been changed to *CTRL+D* to format a drive and *CTRL+P* to format a partition in a drive.

Answer (score 6):

I know I am late. But hoping this will help somebody. This method is same for every ubuntu versions.

First follow the method 1 in [this link](http://www.wikihow.com/Format-a-USB-Flash-Drive-in-Ubuntu) to format the usb drive.

I recommend the erase method as **slow.**

After that your USB drive is formated, but space is now unallocated free space. So you can't use it.

For allocating space you have to click on the **+ sign** below the Volumes bar.

[image]

Then  enter a name for your USB Drive and click create.

[image]

Comment: you can not format if it is bootable this way. does not allow. still

Comment: Never faced a problem with formatting the drive even if it was bootable. Can you pls specify the error message you are getting?

Comment: This worked for me ...as is

Comment: In Ubuntu 19, now it has been changed to *CTRL+D* to format a drive and *CTRL+P* to format a partition in a drive.

Answer (score 4):

1. Open "Disks" and then select the usb drive

   - You will see the partition table (2mb) for the bootable usb.
2. Delete the partition of the partition table
3. Format the usb

Comment: Like this answer, simple and quick. Works fine on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 3):

Try `gparted` - it very good for this

To install it, write next command in Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gparted -y && gksu gparted
```

After you finished to install it, it will be opened now, choose your usb drive form it and can to format it or remove it and create a new one with your file system that you need.

Comment: got bunch of exceptions. so disappointed that I can not just format it like it used to be. had to do it two times. then errors have gone. then I still I had a read-only disk. then did it again - format normal way. not very convenient "feature" not letting to format bootable disk.