# Help on Formatting an USB

Tags: usb, format

I cant format my usb because i tried to install Linux Mint on it and then, when i wanted to erase all data just appears to be 1 empty Gb  on Gparted but the usb are actually 2Gb But file explorer detects the USB [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elDG2.png), 
And the permissions couldn be changed [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63VME.png).

I want to completely erase all the usb to 0 and make a single partition.

I've looked everywhere but I can not find a problem related to mine.

P.D.: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: is your USB have write protect switch?

Comment: Post output of this command. Sudo fdisk -l

Comment: Please go through this answer. http://askubuntu.com/questions/283545/how-to-format-ubuntu-bootable-usb/843838#843838

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a usb-disk or a SD card?
If it's a SD card ,it may be happen because you have your SD card locked.Like this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your usb might be partition as 2 partition (like when we use microSD for writing Raspbian Image). Using gParted, unmount first your USB. Right click on the bar, choose "delete". Make sure you don't have that 2 partition on the USB, it will show information (Unallocated 2GiB). Then right click, New, use FAT32 as the file system.

Now you can make Linux Mint LiveUSB on it.

Or you can use "[SD Formatter](https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/)" in Windows.