# USB locked: how do I reinitialize layout of the whole device

Tags: format, usb-drive

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 onto a USB stick. I installed Ubuntu onto my laptop. When I try to format the USB stick, I get this error message:

```
This partition cannot be modified because it contains a partition table; please reinitialize layout of the whole device. (udisks-error-quark, 11)
```

How do I fix this, so my USB stick is usable again.

Comment: Hi. Have a look at the answer in [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/769079/cant-format-ubuntu-installation-stick). Although it wasn't marked as answered it does look like it fixed the issue.

Comment: Yep I had the same problem and I can verify that recreating partition table with gparted fixes the problem.

Comment: After a few tries with Gparted and a couple of reboots (to help the kernel) I managed to make a new partition (smile) Now I will try with a USB form years ago. I pulled it out of usb without ejecting while using Ubuntu (I love the OS), so it is locked.